# Goodman GM100 Failure to recycle

Tags: furnace

Our Goodman Furnace Model GM100 Serial# 9412063230 will start up and run but will not recycle after initially satisfying the thermostat.  If you wiggle the gray,(ground), wire on the gas valve, it will start again. It may run OK for up to three weeks and then fail, (3 times), to ignite and go into lockout.  This has been going on for about 3 months, but wanted to wait until the warmer weather before getting the furnace replaced, due to a possible extended time of replacement.

Does anyone kow what is in the little black terminal box on the gas valve?

Can the two screws and the black cover,(?), be removed to reconnect whatever is not making a good contact inside?

Comment: If you'd like to add more detail to your question, please use the edit feature instead of asking a whole new question.

Comment: Could you post a photo of the part in question, or include a part number?

Answer (score 1):

If wiggling (which is the correct technical term) can make it stop, or start again, the problem is most likely a broken or mostly broken wire.

The wire can be broken inside of the insulation, and look fine.

I have the broken wire inside the insulation all the time, my cats love my rubber phone charge cord, and will chew it. When I go to charge my phone, the charger will not work sometimes, and i can find a single cat tooth mark that was able to cut the wire.